# Extract tags between tags Java Regex

Tags: java, regex, html-parsing

I want to extract tags between `<body>` and `</body>`

```
String patternHtml = "(*?)<body>(.*?)</body>(*?)";
Pattern rHtml = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher mHtml = rHtml.matcher(html);
```

I don't why but this extracts all tags with `<head>` and `<style>`...

Please: I need to use regex, please don't offer an alternative like a Parser library...

Comment: Have you tried removing `(*?)` from start and end of your regex? Also don't forget to use `find()` method on your matcher object. BTW I hope you wont use this code in some real app, but just learning regex.

Comment: Do you realize that your question is essentially the same as *"I don't why but the screwdriver fails to hit down the nail... Please: I need to use screwdriver, please don't offer an alternative like a hammer..."*? The answer is astonishingly simple: use the right tool for the job!

Comment: @Pshemo yes I tried removing (*?) but it still not working. By the way, why wont I use this code in a real app?

Comment: Because regex is not correct tool for that. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1393766). Also `<body>(.*?)</body>` "*works*" fine for me.

Comment: @BalusC I know it is better to use a parser library. But this is not my question if you see my post..

Comment: show the code where you get the final text

Comment: @Orçunyumarcı “But this is not my question” – Not to put too fine a point on it, the question is stupid. It essentially reads like this: “I am unwilling to accept help.” That’s not a question, that’s a statement – and we dislike it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph you dont have to answer dude.. if it is silly..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about OP has made clear that they’re not interested in help.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to (I quote) "extract tags", which I interpret as opening nodes, within the body statements of your html text, you can use the solution below.

Note that this is **barbaric**. You should not "parse" html with regular expressions (I know *you* know, but other readers might not).

```
// simple html file, has head/body and line breaks
String html = "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<title>Foo</title>\r\n</head>\r\n" +
        "<body>\r\n<h1>Blah</h1>\r\n<h3>Meh</h3>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>";
// the pattern only checks for opening nodes
Pattern tagsWithinBody = Pattern.compile("<\\p{Alnum}+>");
// matcher is applied to whatever text is in between the "<body>" open and close nodes
Matcher matcher = tagsWithinBody.matcher(html.substring(html.indexOf("<body>") + 1, html.indexOf("</body>")));
// iterates over matcher as long as it finds text
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Output:

```
<h1>
<h3>
```